# How to add new webpages from my existing site

Tags: javascript, html, css, post, web-development-server

I'm sorry if this comes off as amateurish, but web development isn't my strong suit. I am working on a project, nothing professional, just a learning exercise

I am curious how I would go about adding new webpages to my website without directly uploading files to my hosting service.

I'm making a blog-style toy website as a training exercise. I essentially want to be able to have a create_new_post.html page with a button that says "post."

Afterward, a new html page gets added to my directory with the blog post that I can now access and read.

I would like to avoid using a framework like ruby on rails. I just want plain old html, css and js code. Is there a good way to go about this? Once again, sorry for the amatuerish nature of this post but im certainly not a web dev.

Comment: You're going to need a backend script to do this

Comment: Might not really possible with plain client-side APIs. You would need to have some sort of a backend/server to serve the webpages, and respond to the requests made by the `post` events to create new pages.

Comment: What would you recommend in order to keep it as simple as possible?